# Add paramters to URL with click functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, urlsearchparams

I want to add parameters to the actual url depending on the selected values. The values will be set with a click function and should work independently from each other.

I've set global variables to store the click function values, but they don't get stored. How can I store the values correctely to work with them in my "URLSearchParams" string?

This is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ozypt9xL/43/).

```
 var btn0;    
 var btn1;
      
      $('.btn0').click(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('data-selected') === 'true') {
      $(this).attr('data-selected', 'false');
      $(this).removeClass('selected');

    } else {
      $(this).closest('tr').find('.btn0').not(this)
        .removeClass('selected').attr('data-selected', 'false');
      $(this).attr('data-selected', 'true');
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      var btn0 = $(this).data("value");
    }
  });
  
      $('.btn1').click(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('data-selected') === 'true') {
            $(this).attr('data-selected', 'false');
            $(this).removeClass('selected');

        } else {
            $(this).closest('tr').find('.btn1').not(this)
            .removeClass('selected').attr('data-selected', 'false');
            $(this).attr('data-selected', 'true');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            var btn1 = $(this).data("value");
        }
    });
    
const params = new URLSearchParams({
  var0: btn0,
  var1: btn1
});   
console.log(params.toString());
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Twisty Hi, a complete fiddle is included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ckd1j6u0/

**HTML**

```
<table class="container">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="tier0">
      <td class="talent-cell">
        <div class="btn btn0" data-value="a">Test0</div>
      </td>
      <td class="talent-cell">
        <div class="btn btn0" data-value="b">Test1</div>
      </td>
      <td class="talent-cell">
        <div class="btn btn0" data-value="c">Test2</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tier1">
      <td class="talent-cell">
        <div class="btn btn1" data-value="d">Test0</div>
      </td>
      <td class="talent-cell">
        <div class="btn btn1" data-value="e">Test1</div>
      </td>
      <td class="talent-cell">
        <div class="btn btn1" data-value="f">Test2</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var selected = {
    var0: null,
    var1: null
  };
  $('.btn').click(function(event) {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    $(".selected", row).removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    if ($(".selected").length == 2) {
      $("tr").each(function(i, el) {
        selected['var' + i] = $(".selected", el).attr("data-value");
      });
      var params = new URLSearchParams(selected);
      console.log(params.toString());
    }
  });
});
```

This uses just `selected` class instead of trying to also manage `data-selected` attributes. The code first makes sure only one button in each row is selected. It then populates an Object. When two selections have been made, it then creates the parameters for URL.

Comment: Thanks. If you just click a selection from the first row it doesn't appear. You need to make a selection in the second row to get the result from the first row, too. Otherwise this would be perfect.

Comment: @Keroster you can remove the condition, `if ($(".selected").length == 2) {`. This will allow the potential for `null` entry in one of the variables.

Answer (score 1):

The params object does not reference to variables, but is initialized with empty btn0 and btn1. Re declaring btn0 and btn1 inside the click assignments makes no sense, because these will be new variables.
You have to use the set function to manipulate key value pairs in params.

Here is a working example:

```js
 var btn0;    
 var btn1;
      
      $('.btn0').click(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('data-selected') === 'true') {
      $(this).attr('data-selected', 'false');
      $(this).removeClass('selected');

    } else {
      $(this).closest('tr').find('.btn0').not(this)
        .removeClass('selected').attr('data-selected', 'false');
      $(this).attr('data-selected', 'true');
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      params.set('var0', $(this).data("value"));
      console.log(params.toString());
    }
  });
  
      $('.btn1').click(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('data-selected') === 'true') {
            $(this).attr('data-selected', 'false');
            $(this).removeClass('selected');

        } else {
            $(this).closest('tr').find('.btn1').not(this)
            .removeClass('selected').attr('data-selected', 'false');
            $(this).attr('data-selected', 'true');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            params.set('var1', $(this).data("value"));
            console.log(params.toString());
        }
    });
    
const params = new URLSearchParams({
  var0: btn0,
  var1: btn1
});   
console.log(params.toString());
```