# Select one data-attribute per table row and cell

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html table:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" class="test">
  <tr>
    <td class="talent-cell"><div class="btn7" data-value="0">aaa</div></td>
    <td class="talent-cell"><div class="btn8" data-value="1">bbb</div></td>
     <td class="talent-cell"><div class="btn9" data-value="2">ccc</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="talent-cell"><div class="btn7" data-value="0">ddd</div></td>
    <td class="talent-cell"><div class="btn8" data-value="1">eee</div></td>
    <td class="talent-cell"><div class="btn9" data-value="2">fff</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="talent-cell"><div class="btn7" data-value="0">ggg</div></td>
    <td class="talent-cell"><div class="btn8" data-value="1">hhh</div></td>
    <td class="talent-cell"><div class="btn9" data-value="2">iii</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you click on a "div attribute" inside a table cell I need to get the "data-value" of the clicked div attribute. After that I build a query string to use it with "URLSearchParams". This works so far.

Now I need a certain condition. It should be only allowed to select one div-attribute per table row and column. But I don't know how to implement this condition in my code.

This is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a0h4ejfu/12/) and the code:

```
var btn7;
var btn8;
var btn9;

$('.btn7').click(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('data-selected') === 'true') {
        $(this).attr('data-selected', 'false');
        $(this).removeClass('selected');

    } else {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.btn7').not(this)
        .removeClass('selected').attr('data-selected', 'false');
        $(this).attr('data-selected', 'true');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        params.set('var7', $(this).data("value"));
        window.history.replaceState({}, '', `?${params}`);
    }
});

$('.btn8').click(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('data-selected') === 'true') {
        $(this).attr('data-selected', 'false');
        $(this).removeClass('selected');

    } else {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.btn8').not(this)
        .removeClass('selected').attr('data-selected', 'false');
        $(this).attr('data-selected', 'true');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        params.set('var8', $(this).data("value"));
        window.history.replaceState({}, '', `?${params}`);
    }
});

$('.btn9').click(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('data-selected') === 'true') {
        $(this).attr('data-selected', 'false');
        $(this).removeClass('selected');

    } else {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.btn9').not(this)
        .removeClass('selected').attr('data-selected', 'false');
        $(this).attr('data-selected', 'true');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        params.set('var9', $(this).data("value"));
        window.history.replaceState({}, '', `?${params}`);
    }
});


const params = new URLSearchParams({
    var7: btn7,
    var8: btn8,
    var9: btn9,
});
```

Comment: I'd use radio buttons - all buttons in the same row need to have the same name.

Comment: @user1599011 That would not help as the single selection rule should apply to rows and columns alike.

Comment: Your code should be refactored it's too much repetative. as for implementation, maybe as you select a btn7, set some attribute on every btn7.parent.find(td) and on every .btn7. That attribute would tell not to select that cell.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add paramters to URL with click functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72702525/add-paramters-to-url-with-click-functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Idea**

Mark each table cell with a `data-` attribute indicating its respective row and column, and maintain 2 arrays that hold the currently selected element (if any) for each of the columns and row.

**Implementation**

The following code implements the selection logic. Based on the arrays holding the currently active selections you can visit all relevant elements and assemble the parameters when you send a request to the server.

The specs of single cell/row selection implies that there will usually be rows and columns that do not carry a selection.

Note that the case of expressly deselecting a cell is not handled.

The code does not resort to jquery.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SO _: 1-in-a-row, 1-in-a-col selection</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .selected {
              background: #333;
              color: #fff;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            let a_colSelection = new Array(3)
              , a_rowSelection = new Array(3)
              ;
            
            document.addEventListener ( 'DOMContentLoaded', () => { 
                Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div[data-row][data-col]')).forEach ( el => {
                    el.addEventListener ( 'click', eve => {
                        let c = parseInt(eve.target.getAttribute('data-col'))
                          , r = parseInt(eve.target.getAttribute('data-row'))
                          ;
                        
                        if (a_colSelection[c] !== undefined) {
                            document.querySelector(`div[data-col="${a_colSelection[c][1]}"][data-row="${a_colSelection[c][0]}"]`).classList.remove("selected");
                        }
                        if (a_rowSelection[r] !== undefined) {
                            document.querySelector(`div[data-col="${a_rowSelection[r][1]}"][data-row="${a_rowSelection[r][0]}"]`).classList.remove("selected");
                        }
                        a_colSelection[c] = [r, c];
                        a_rowSelection[r] = [r, c];
                        document.querySelector(`div[data-col="${a_colSelection[c][1]}"][data-row="${a_rowSelection[r][0]}"]`).classList.add("selected");
                    }); 
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1" cellpadding="5" class="test">
          <tr>
            <td class="talent-cell"><div data-value="0" data-col="0" data-row="0">aaa</div></td>
            <td class="talent-cell"><div data-value="1" data-col="1" data-row="0">bbb</div></td>
             <td class="talent-cell"><div data-value="2" data-col="2" data-row="0">ccc</div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="talent-cell"><div data-value="0" data-col="0" data-row="1">ddd</div></td>
            <td class="talent-cell"><div data-value="1" data-col="1" data-row="1">eee</div></td>
            <td class="talent-cell"><div data-value="2" data-col="2" data-row="1">fff</div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="talent-cell"><div data-value="0" data-col="0" data-row="2">ggg</div></td>
            <td class="talent-cell"><div data-value="1" data-col="1" data-row="2">hhh</div></td>
            <td class="talent-cell"><div data-value="2" data-col="2" data-row="2">iii</div></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First of all, thank you. This is a more difficult code than I've expected. So I need to ask something. When I use  `console.log(a_colSelection);` or  `console.log(a_rowSelection);` the arrays are empty even when I've made a selection. So how can I find the data-value of the actual selected cell?

Comment: No, the arrays are not empty. You can check this by selecting a cell in a row or column that already contains a selected cell, which will be (visibly) deselected. Technically a css class is removed, for the code to do that the selection arrays must be filled.

Comment: If there is no selection at all, though (ie. after loading, before the first click in a cell),  the arrays are empty indeed.

Comment: Sorry, to ask again. Could you give me an example how do I get the selected cell value to use it it my query string?

Comment: No problem. `a_colSelection[c]` gives the pair `[r, c]` of row/column coordinates of the selected cell in column`c`, or undefined if no column is selected. Similarly for `a_rowSelection[r]` and selected cell in row `r`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/dzng31f5/39/

**HTML**

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" class="test">
  <tr class="var7">
    <td class="talent-cell">
      <div class="btn" data-value="0">aaa</div>
    </td>
    <td class="talent-cell">
      <div class="btn" data-value="1">bbb</div>
    </td>
    <td class="talent-cell">
      <div class="btn" data-value="2">ccc</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="var8">
    <td class="talent-cell">
      <div class="btn" data-value="0">ddd</div>
    </td>
    <td class="talent-cell">
      <div class="btn" data-value="1">eee</div>
    </td>
    <td class="talent-cell">
      <div class="btn" data-value="2">fff</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="var9">
    <td class="talent-cell">
      <div class="btn" data-value="0">ggg</div>
    </td>
    <td class="talent-cell">
      <div class="btn" data-value="1">hhh</div>
    </td>
    <td class="talent-cell">
      <div class="btn" data-value="2">iii</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I adjusted the HTML Structure, such that each Row has a Class that represents the Index name that will be used in the Object.

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  function checkCol(colIndex, table) {
    var result = true;
    console.log("Col Index:" + colIndex)
    $("tbody tr", table).each(function(i, el) {
      result = result && !$("td:eq(" + colIndex + ") div.btn", el).hasClass("selected");
    });
    return !result;
  }

  function checkRow(target, row) {
    var isInCol = checkCol($(target).parent().index(), $(row).closest("table"));
    if (!isInCol) {
      if ($(".selected", row).length) {
        $(".selected", row).removeClass("selected");
        $(target).addClass("selected");
      } else {
        $(target).addClass("selected");
      }
    }
  }
  
  var selected = {};
  
  $('.btn').click(function(event) {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    checkRow(this, row);
    $(".test tbody tr").each(function(i, el) {
      selected[$(el).attr("class")] = $(".selected", el).length ? $(".selected", el).data("value") : "";
    });
    console.log(selected);
    var params = new URLSearchParams(selected);
    console.log(params.toString());
  });
});
```

You can now use `selected` as your Data in a POST or GET call.

**Updated**

I had missed that each Row and Column needed to be unique. Code is updated to use Functions to check both conditions.

Comment: Two cells in a column can be selected.

Comment: Thanks, but sadly you can select two columns.

Comment: @collapsar I had missed this in OP; updated.

Answer (score 0):

> *"Now I need a certain condition. It should be only allowed to select one div-attribute per table row and column."*

The versatility of jQuery is leveraged by the use of `this` because it narrows down from many objects (all `<td>` in `<table>`) to a single object (`<td>` the user clicked). The behavior needed is common with radio button groups called *"mutual exclusive selection"*, using `.not(this)` makes it simple.

In HTML,

- assign a common class to each `<div>` (ex. `'.col'`, see **Figure I**)
- assign a class to each `<div>` that corresponds to the value of it's `[data-value]` (ex. `'.c0'`, see **Figure I**)

  **Figure I**

  ```html
  <div class='col c0' data-value='0'>
  ```

I did not include the `params` part in OP since it's beyond the scope of the question (*see beginning of this answer*). The values are stored in object `C` and is easily accessible (ex. `C.c0`).

BTW, I hope that the logic is different with your real code. For example, there is no difference between `.c0` 2nd row and `.c0` 1st row.

**Details are commented in example below**

```js
// Declare object to store [data-value]
let C = {};

// Any click on a .col calls the event handler
$('.col').on('click', function() {
  // Flip .selected on this .col
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  // If this .col is flipped to be .selected...
  if ($(this).is('.selected')) {
    //... get this .col [data-value] (0, 1, or 2)...
    let idx = $(this).data('value');
    /*
    ... find all .c0, .c1, or .c2 BUT NOT this .col and
    remove .selected from them...
    */
    $('.c' + idx).not(this).removeClass('selected');
    /*
    ... then find the closest <tr>, then find all .col of
    <tr> BUT NOT this .col and remove .selected from them
    */
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.col')
      .not(this).removeClass('selected');
    // set key 'c0', 'c1', or 'c2' of C to this .col [data-value]
    C['c'+idx] = $(this).data('value');
  }
  console.log(C);
});
```

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" class="test">
  <tr>
    <td><div class="col c0" data-value="0">aaa</div></td>
    <td><div class="col c1" data-value="1">bbb</div></td>
    <td><div class="col c2" data-value="2">ccc</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="col c0" data-value="0">aaa</div></td>
    <td><div class="col c1" data-value="1">bbb</div></td>
    <td><div class="col c2" data-value="2">ccc</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="col c0" data-value="0">aaa</div></td>
    <td><div class="col c1" data-value="1">bbb</div></td>
    <td><div class="col c2" data-value="2">ccc</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```